# How to start Android notification as minimized

Tags: android, notifications, minimized

I'm creating a notification with both minimized (normal) and maximized (bigView) views.
But when I launch the notification it always starts with maximized view.
Is there any way I can set the default view to the minimized one ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain What you mean by minimized here.

Comment: I edited the text, minimized is normal while maximized is BigView view.

Comment: Did you try Custom Notification.

Comment: @Homosapiens, how do I set the view to `normal` view in custom Notification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The system UI chooses which version to show.